# How to extract file paths in the folder with partial match

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf`. I want to match the character in column `FAM` to the file names matching character before `_` in the directory called `/mypath/`files, and replace the values in FAM column with full path of the respective files.

files in /mypath:

```
1_reca.44.bam
12_reca.xx.4.bam
AMA_xtt.33.bam 
SMA_xtt.33.bam
```

mydf

```
sn      FAM            PAT
1       1              all 
2       12             non
3       AMA            non
```

result

```
sn      FAM                   PAT
1       mypath/1_reca.44.bam      all 
2       mypath/12_reca.xx.4.bam   non
3       mypath/AMA_xtt.33.bam     non
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `match/paste/sub`.  We `match` the elements in the 'FAM' column with the substring of 'files' (after the removing the characters from  `_` to the end of the string.  The numeric index can be used to select the elements from 'files', and `paste` it with 'mypath' to create the updated 'FAM' column.

```
mydf$FAM<- paste('mypath',  
           files[match(mydf$FAM,sub('_.*', '', files))], sep='/')
mydf$FAM
#[1] "mypath/1_reca.44.bam"    "mypath/12_reca.xx.4.bam" 
# "mypath/AMA_xtt.33.bam"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. What if I just need to select from the pool of files with .bam extension as I have in my updated question?

Comment: @MAPK I updated the solution.  From your original post, I thought `.BAM` should be deleted, so I used `sub`.  In the new one, the second `sub` is removed.